# Spark Kryo FieldSerializer for unregistered objects

Tags: apache-spark, kryo

If spark is setup to use KryoSerializer

```
spark.serializer = org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer
```

It seems to use `com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer` for classes that are not registered explicitly (i.e. `FieldSerializer` is the `defaultSerializer`).

If you are not defining your custom serializer, then what is the benefit of registering the classes a-priori using `SparkConf.registerKryoClasses`?